# Pandoc sourcecode block with figure caption

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

when pandoc generates an pdf out of an markdown file all images got caption (Figure 1: some caption) in a floating block.

How could be done the same for source code?

I would like to keep the option to generate HTML and don't use Latex specific command, if possible.

Imagined input:

````
```bash {caption: "A git commit"}
git commit file1.txt --message="A commit message"
```
````

Output:

```
git commit file1.txt --message="A commit message"
```

Figure 1: A git commit

Comment: It would be ideal if you could provide your audience with a sample document to work with that replicates your current behaviour.

Comment: Pandoc provides those kind of figures [only for images](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-implicit_figures). You can, however write a [pandoc filter](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html) to do what you want...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Fenced code blocks](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#fenced-code-blocks) like this:

```
~~~ { .bash caption="A git commit"}
git commit file1.txt --message="A commit message"
~~~
```

Also please note that you need to use pandoc with the `--listing` to get this working.

**Source**:

- [Official documentation](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#fenced-code-blocks)
- [this Github issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/673)